# Keyboard not working on my lenovo S10 Netbook

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook

I tried to install ubuntu 10.10 on my Lenovo S10 netbook. While installing, we have to add user name and password etc. But my keyboard does not support at that time. Why? Also I installed trial version, at that time also my keyboard is not working. Mouse works better. Please guide

Comment: you may suffer from [bug #677633](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/677633), ACPI related

Comment: moata_u, I have the same problem. I booted from USB, so USB isn't the problem. I've read other reports of people having the same problem with other netbooks. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook on a Lenovo S10-3C. Other reports: Asus EeePC 1015P with Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Remix http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610264 Ubuntu 10.10, laptop not specified http://superuser.com/questions/225234/keyboard-not-detected-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-10-10 [EDIT] I've exchanged the S10-3c for an S10-3s. The keyboard works but this on model I can't get any ethernet or wireless connectivity. :/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug report has been submitted for the Linux kernel team.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/677633

A bad solution is here:
http://s10lenovo.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=4482

It's bad, but it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

please do the following :
1. restart computer.
2. usually access the BIOS by pressing the DEL key during the POST.
3. make sure that USB port (cant remember exact name option) enabled.